# Can't figure out return type with function trait

Tags: rust

I'm trying to return a relatively complex type from a function but I can't figure out what the actual type is and keep getting

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
```

specifically

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:45:5
   |
20 | fn my_function() -> FmtHandle {
   |                     --------- expected `Handle<tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<Layered<FilterFn<for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a tracing::Metadata<'b>) -> bool>, Registry>, DefaultFields, Format, BoxMakeWriter>, Layered<FilterFn<for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a tracing::Metadata<'b>) -> bool>, Registry>>` because of return type
...
27 |     let env = tracing_subscriber::filter::FilterFn::new(|metadata| {
   |                                                         ---------- the found closure
...
45 |     fmt_handle
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `Handle<Layer<Layered<FilterFn<fn(&...) -> ...>, ...>, ..., ..., ...>, ...>`, found `Handle<Layer<Layered<FilterFn<...>, ...>, ..., ..., ...>, ...>`
   |
   = note: expected struct `Handle<tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<Layered<FilterFn<for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a tracing::Metadata<'b>) -> bool>, _>, _, _, _>, Layered<FilterFn<for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a tracing::Metadata<'b>) -> bool>, _>>`
              found struct `Handle<tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<Layered<FilterFn<[closure@src/main.rs:27:57: 27:67]>, _>, _, _, _>, Layered<FilterFn<[closure@src/main.rs:27:57: 27:67]>, _>>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `test-bin` (bin "test-bin") due to previous error
```

my code is:

```rust
use tracing_subscriber::{fmt, prelude::*, reload};

type FilterClosure = fn(_: &tracing::Metadata<'_>) -> bool;
type FmtHandle = tracing_subscriber::reload::Handle<
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<
        tracing_subscriber::layer::Layered<
            tracing_subscriber::filter::FilterFn<FilterClosure>,
            tracing_subscriber::registry::Registry,
        >,
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::DefaultFields,
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Format,
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::writer::BoxMakeWriter,
    >,
    tracing_subscriber::layer::Layered<
        tracing_subscriber::filter::FilterFn<FilterClosure>,
        tracing_subscriber::registry::Registry,
    >,
>;

fn my_function() -> FmtHandle {
    let fmt_layer = fmt::Layer::new().with_writer(
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::writer::BoxMakeWriter::new(std::io::stdout),
    );
    let (fmt_layer, fmt_handle) = reload::Layer::new(fmt_layer);
    print_type_of(&fmt_handle);

    let env = tracing_subscriber::filter::FilterFn::new(|metadata| {
        println!("file: {:?}", metadata.file());
        println!("module: {:?}", metadata.module_path());
        *metadata.level() <= tracing_subscriber::filter::LevelFilter::ERROR
    });

    tracing_subscriber::registry::Registry::default()
        .with(env)
        .with(fmt_layer)
        .try_init()
        .unwrap();

    tracing::trace!("test trace");
    tracing::debug!("test debug");
    tracing::info!("test info");
    tracing::warn!("test warn");
    tracing::error!("test error");

    fmt_handle
}

fn main() {
    let _ = my_function();
}
fn print_type_of<T>(_: &T) {
    println!("{}", std::any::type_name::<T>())
}
```

with dependencies

```
tracing = { version = "0.1.37" }
tracing-subscriber = { version = "0.3.17" }
```

---

If you remove the return type on `my_function` the program runs succesfully and `print_type_of` prints the type but using this printed type doesn't resolve the problem.

I would also like to be able to store this type within some struct `struct MyStruct { x: FmtHandle }`.

Comment: The problem is that you can't name closures so writing a concrete return type is impossible, it will have to be some `impl Trait` of sorts.

Comment: I have attempted to use a function and it doesn't work and I can't find a way to do `impl Trait`.

Comment: Replace `FilterClosure` in your `FmtHandle` with `impl Fn(_: &tracing::Metadata<'_>) -> bool` except it can't bein a `type` declaration on stable. So put your definition directly as the return type.

Comment: [type_alias_impl_trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/type-alias-impl-trait.html) is the feature needed to use `impl` in a type alias if you're on nightly and don't mind using a feature flag.

Comment: I think I also need to store my type in a struct, this seems to create another problem, I will expand my question to include this apologies for not including it earlier

Comment: I can't figure out how to get this to work with generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no way to name a closure (yet, on nightly you can use a [type alias with an `impl Trait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/unstable-book/language-features/type-alias-impl-trait.html)) and by your own comment you need to also store the return type in a struct you have to use generic parameters for them:

```rust
type FmtHandle<F, G> = tracing_subscriber::reload::Handle<
    tracing_subscriber::fmt::Layer<
        tracing_subscriber::layer::Layered<
            tracing_subscriber::filter::FilterFn<F>,
            tracing_subscriber::registry::Registry,
        >,
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::DefaultFields,
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::format::Format,
        tracing_subscriber::fmt::writer::BoxMakeWriter,
    >,
    tracing_subscriber::layer::Layered<
        tracing_subscriber::filter::FilterFn<G>,
        tracing_subscriber::registry::Registry,
    >,
>;
```

You'll then also have to adjust the struct and function accordingly:

```rust
fn my_function(
) -> FmtHandle<impl Fn(&tracing::Metadata<'_>) -> bool, impl Fn(&tracing::Metadata<'_>) -> bool> {
    // ...
}

struct MyType<F, G> {
    handle: FmtHandle<F, G>
}
```

Comment: Sucks that this requires polluting the codebase with a generic thats only ever has 1 value. But this does actually work unlike anything I came up with, thankyou.